# post-head emotive modifiers such as "in the world" and "the hell"

Tags: english-to-german

Does German allow post-head modifiers such as *in the world* and *the hell* as in the following English examples?

1. *What the hell are you doing?*
2. *Where in the world do you think you're going?*
3. *Who the fuck closed my computer?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course.

The literal (except "fuck", which doesn't have a corelate in German) translations of your idioms are:

1. Was zum Teufel/zur Hölle tust du da?
2. Wo um alle[s in der] Welt glaubst du, dass du hingehst?
3. Wer zum Teufel hat meinen Computer zugemacht?

Comment: Thank you! And what about for *welche*?

Comment: I don't get your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you ask *Welchen um alle Welt Bleistift hast du benutzt?* or *Welchen zur Hölle Bleistift hast du benutzt?*

Comment: Hm ... eher "Wo um alles in der Welt", oder?

Comment: @mtwde Ich kenne beides. Da es sich da eher um eine spontanen Aggressionsausbruch handelt, ist man da wohl eher nicht so wortreich...

Comment: @BrettReynolds The Bleistift examples don't work in German. Can you give an english example for that?

Comment: @puck No, it doesn't work in English either. It seems like a strange limitation where all the interrogative words work **except** *which*. So I wondered if the same constraints held in German. It appears that they do.

Comment: It's *Welchen Bleistift zum Teufel hast du benutzt?* or *Welchen Bleistift hast du zum Teufel benutzt?*

Comment: Interesting! Those options are not avaiablel in English.

Comment: zu 3) geht noch "Wer hat verflucht/verfickt nochmal meinen Computer zugemacht." Etwas näher an der Vorlage ^^

Comment: Ich werfe mal noch ein "Wer zum Henker..." in den Raum